# How to prevent humans from logging in to a service account?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

There are several service accounts that are being used for monitoring and communication between applications that can be seen in an sys.sql_logins page.

Passwords belonging to these accounts are hashed and set to never expire. Since these accounts have their "
`is_disabled` parameter set to `0`, the regulatory body looking into these accounts cannot give the assurance that they are service accounts.

I somehow need to provide proof that these accounts cannot be logged in by a human. What parameter can I change so I can provide proof that we cannot log in to these accounts? Would a service account still function if `is_disabled` parameter for that login is set to `1`?

Question is somewhat theoretical as I cannot make changes to the application without a valid business reason.

Comment: There is no such parameter; if a person has access to the credentials of that account, they could authenticate as that account. This is one of the reasons why such accounts should have the **minimal** amount of access it needs to do its role, as anyone using it likely has more access that the [service] account does (so can't abuse the account for permissions elevation).

Comment: Even if you don't know the passwords, what would stop you from changing the password and login to the accounts? The regulatory body probably don't know what they're talking about

Comment: @ThomA Would you say that if a login has its ´is_disabled´ attribute set to ´0´, it would stop functioning?

Comment: No, because it's enabled. *Most* `LOGIN`s likely have `0` for `is_disabled`.

Comment: @siggemannen Because any changes made with an account with admin privileges require you to disclose a valid business reason. Access to such accounts are time-limited, tied to a specific user account and any actions you take are logged. The issue here is anyone with the credentials to these service accounts can login them. This needs to be prevented somehow.

Comment: You can never prove noone has passwords to something, so this is a waste of time. Even a hashed password needs to be stored somewhere, otherwise you can't use it, and therefor someone can look there

Comment: @ThomA What I meant to ask was if I set `is_disabled` to `1` , could the service account still be able to be used by applications themselves, but logically if a user cannot log in, an application cannot log in as well. Thank you both for the explanations, this request from the regulatory body seems to be unreasonable.

Comment: No, if the account is disabled, it's disabled. You can't authenticate as that account.

Comment: "this request from the regulatory body seems to be unreasonable." - maybe unreasonable to you but the regulators might have a different opinion ;-) It seems you already have a vaulting solution that provides limited access to the credentials with logging. I would think that would be a good enough control for service account access by humans except for the fact the passwords are set to never expire.

Comment: Why not use gMSA accounts with Windows Authentication? Then no passwords are used to login. That's the real solution: remove the need for passwords to be stored anywhere except the Domain Controller.